# how to get enums value using case classes in scala

Tags: scala

I am trying to implement enum using case class in scala.

with reference to question [type parameter in traits to define data types in scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45521153/type-parameter-in-traits-to-define-data-types-in-scala)

```
sealed trait ElementType[+A] {
      def length: Int
 }

sealed trait Tag extends ElementType[Int] {
     override def length: Int = 0
 }

 case object Tag100 extends Tag

sealed trait Value[+A] extends ElementType[A] {
   override def length: Int = 0
}

final case class Value100(a: String) extends Value[String] {
   override def length: Int = a.length
}

case class MessageId(tag: Tag, value: Value[String]){

}

case class MessageRepType(tag: Tag[Int], value:MessageType ){

}

sealed trait Message[T] {def typeCode: T;}

object MessageTypes {
 sealed trait MessageType[Int] extends Message[Int]
 case object TYPE1 extends MessageType[Int]{val typeCode = 0;}
 case object TYPE2 extends MessageType[Int]{val typeCode = 1;}
}

  case class ABCMessage (
                    id:MessageId,
                    messageType:MessageRepType)
```

I want to print a message with something like below id and type in new line

```
   type        value
   100        abc              
   200        0
```

**Explanation:**        100 abc represents MessageId
                        200 0   represnets MessageRepType and O represent TYPE1

Comment: Have a look at https://github.com/lloydmeta/enumeratum

Comment: @cchantep,I have updated the question ,want to get value of case object

Comment: What's wrong with `println(message.id + "\t" + message.type.typeCode)`

Comment: Please don't post code that doesn't compile unless you are asking, "Why doesn't this code compile?" In all cases you should post the absolutely smallest amount of code necessary to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: @jwvh apologies for this .I have updated the code

Comment: It still doesn't compile because `Tag`, as you've defined it, does not take type parameters, so `Tag[Int]` is wrong.

Comment: corrected it ,seems no error apologies for this

Comment: It seems you forget to add for which input it should produce the expected output (you mentioned in other comment that it is not a `Seq[ABCMessage]`.)

Comment: I have mentioned the output,I didnt get your point

Comment: ok I have update case class ABCMessage (
                    id:MessageId,
                    messageType:MessageRepType)..probably this is causing the confusion

Comment: @GáborBakos updated the question.hope it clarifies

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your "message" is a `ABCMessage(MessageId(Tag100, Value100("abc"),MessageRepType(Tag200, TYPE1))` (also assuming `Tag200` is similar to `Tag100` and `case class MessageRepType(tag: Tag[Int], value:MessageType)` is `case class MessageRepType(tag: Tag, value:MessageType)` and `sealed trait MessageType extends Message[Int]`):

```
val sep = System.lineSeparator
def convertTag(tag: Tag): Int = tag match {
    case Tag100 => 100
    case Tag200 => 200
}
def convertMessageId(message: MessageId): String = {
  val typ = convertTag(message.tag)
  val value = message.value match {
    case Value100(v) => v
  }
  s"$typ\t$value"
}
val id = convertMessageId(message.id)
def convertType(message: MessgeRepType): String = {
  val typ = convertTag(message.tag)
  val value = message.value match {// I would put typeCode to MessageType, but it is not there, so pattern matching
    case TYPE1 => TYPE1.typeCode
    case TYPE2 => TYPE2.typeCode
  }
  s"$typ\t$value"
}
val typ = convertType(message)
val message: ABCMessage = ABCMessage(MessageId(Tag100, Value100("abc"),MessageRepType(Tag200, TYPE1))
val messageAsString = Seq("type\tvalue", id, typ).mkString(sep)
println(messageAsString)
```

Comment: Updated answer.

Comment: Can we discuss in chat  room.I have pinged u

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45551502/scala-product-iterator-for-case-classes  ,I am referring to a general solution to print members of case class .My case class as enum may have 10-15 value.not advisable to have  a case match if number grows

Comment: Well, you have not much options, I guess you have seen my comment and could not  apply it:

> // I would put typeCode to MessageType, but it is not there, so pattern matching

Comment: i think this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45551502/scala-product-iterator-for-case-classes explains my question better

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45566851/override-case-class-method-in-scala what I am trying  to finally achieve.apologies i am new to scala so proabably taking time to explain my requirement

Answer (score 0):

A different approach as still not sure what you want to achieve. The other answer with pattern matching is what I would prefer, [more idiomatic](https://www.coursera.org/learn/progfun1/lecture/cdHAM/lecture-4-6-pattern-matching).

You can use something like a simplified the visitor pattern (removed the irrelevant parts):

```
trait Show {
  def show: String
}

sealed trait Tag extends Show {
  override def show: String = this.getClass.getSimpleName.init
}

//object Tag {
  case object Tag100 extends Tag
  case object Tag200 extends Tag
//}
```

This way you can show the tags like this:

```
Tag100.show // Tag100
```

The case classes can also implement `show`:

```
sealed trait Value[+A] extends Show {
  def v: String
  override def show: String = v
}
case class Value100(v: String) extends Value[String]
```

You can use this in other methods too to implement the printing you want:

```
def convertMessageId(message: MessageId): String = {
  val typ = message.tag.show
  val value = message.value.show
  s"$typ\t$value"
}
val id = convertMessageId(message.id)
def convertType(message: MessgeRepType): String = {
  val typ = message.tag.show
  val value = message.value.show
  s"$typ\t$value"
}

val message: ABCMessage = ABCMessage(MessageId(Tag100, Value100("abc"),MessageRepType(Tag200, TYPE1))
val messageAsString = Seq("type\tvalue", id, typ).mkString(sep)
println(messageAsString)
```

If type safety and easy, generic usage is also important, take a look at [Shapeless](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless)' offerings and [this blog post](http://www.cakesolutions.net/teamblogs/solving-problems-in-a-generic-way-using-shapeless).

If type safety is not so important, maybe for your use case it is enough to know that case classes implement [`Product`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.3/scala/Product.html), so you can visit them one-by-one and use its content.

Alternative solution might be to convert your datastructure to for example JSON (there are many Scala libs for that) and use that for further processing. Still generic, but not type-safe.

([This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8618082) might also be relevant.)