# override case class method in scala

Tags: scala, case-class

I am trying to override a method of trait in my case class which want to display all the members of case class. I am using it for debugging purpose.

```
trait A{
   def myMethod(employee:Emp):Unit
}

case class Emp(id:String,name:String) extends A {
   override def myMethod(employee: Emp): Unit = 
              emp.productIterator.toList.foreach(println)
}
```

other possible way to do this is

```
    emp.productIterator.toList.mkString("\n")
```

to declare `Emp("10","abc")`. I am new to `Scala`, not sure how to call the override method of `trait`.

1. I am not sure if any other generic way to achieve this functionality
   to get string form of case class members.
2. Efficient way to use trait and case class to achieve this
   functionality.I want to understand how apply method and companion
   objects can be implemented .
3. I want to implement `logging` instead of using `println`. Can anyone
   suggest a tutorial for it?

Comment: Why not having the implementation in the `trait`?

Comment: Nice suggestion if we do it in trait we need to override in case class since  it extends it

Comment: need not. Also as `myMethod` is stateless (not related to the state of a `A` instance) would rather implement it in a companion `object`

Comment: Your question is unclear. What does logging have to do with case classes?

Comment: Logging has a purpose as I have a different use case for this.

Comment: @cchantep I am new to scala ....may be i am not able to explain my points very clearly.Do u mean that i should create a companion object for trait /case class.not sure what u actually mean

Comment: companion for trait as stateless/not related to self instance

Comment: @cchantep can u give a example please so that i can understand.It will be helpful in understanding the concepts.so with respect to my question i will create object A extends A to create companion object for it

Comment: @cchantep updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Previous answer was because i didn't understood your question right. This should answer your question:

If you want this only for debugging purposes you can use it like that:

```
trait A{
  def myMethod(employee:Emp):Unit
}

case class Emp(id:String,name:String) extends A {
  override def myMethod(employee: Emp): Unit =
    this.productIterator.toList.foreach(println)
}

Emp("1", "2").myMethod(None.orNull)
```

But more logical would be to use object with this nonGeneric method:

```
case class Emp(id:String,name:String)

object A{
  def myMethod(employee: Emp):Unit = {
    employee.productIterator.toList.foreach(println)
  }
}

A.myMethod(Emp("1", "2"))
```

For logging purposes you can use just apache  [log4j](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/scala-api.html)